# PHP Include() - Header and Footer

Tags: php, header, include

I use php include() for my header, footer, navigation etc.

I have the following code repeated on each of my pages

```
  <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Can I store the data i am including somewhere for loading speed??

Comment: Faster how?  You could cache the output of the total page (header+content+footer) and load that if the cache isn't in some way old... but that's not going to make your code faster/easier, and may not show much benefits to the end user (depending on what else is going on in your PHP - DB lookups or just mostly static content)

Comment: go take a look at frameworks. Other then that, you could have header and footer in a single file, just in different methods, so you include it once, but call it whenever you need it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you aren't experiencing any problems with loading pages, you shouldn't be concerned of a faster ways.
2. If you're experiencing some problems with page loading, these problems certainly NOT from the way you're including headers. You have *to profile* your site execution and find **real** part that slows whole thing down.