# Site Optimization and Header/Footer pages

Tags: php, optimization, responsive-design

Is it advisable, in terms of site optimization, to have a header.php and footer.php that I include in each of my page?  I've done this in the past to keep things organized but is it best practice in page speed optimization?

Comment: That is such a strange question (false dilemma?). Server-side architecture can be a lot more imaginative.

Comment: I think it's legitimate to ask if using that type of architecture is successful in making a site faster in speed, or if it even matters at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532526/php-include-header-and-footer

Comment: If you're worried about performance you really shouldn't be looking at the name of the files you're including. You should be looking at how many you're including and whether maybe some of those can be delayed. You quickly enter into the area of autoloading which completely does away with the notion of `header.php` and `footer.php`. Your question is like: _should I use a 12V electric motor for my lawn mower?_ there are just so many considerations. How big is your lawn? What about a gas motor? Don't confuse optimization with design, they are related but separate concerns.

Comment: The responsive web design has nothing to do with this.  I just adding if for information!  All I'm worried about here is speed optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including a header.php and footer.php file on the page will mean that the backend system will need to construct the page before serving the HTML requested.

This is an expected behaviour for any sites running on a CMS or using a scripting language (like PHP), and it's an acceptable trade off because the performance impacts are minimal compared to the improvements to maintaining the site (i.e you only have to update something in the header in one file and it is done for the entire site).

To improve your performance you can add a reverse proxy such as

- [Varnish Cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)
- [Squid Proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/)

If you don't have any experience setting those up then look at using

- [Cloud Flare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) (Free account available)
- [Fastly](http://www.fastly.com/)

Answer (score -1):

responsive web design not matter what you do on server side. 
if you want responsive web design read more about:

- media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
- bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
- jquery mobile: http://api.jquerymobile.com/

Thanks

Comment: I was just saying it was a responsive web design.  I know it has nothing to do with server side.